# Textfield data in tableview erasing while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

I have taken two custom tableview cells in one tableview.One cell is for textfield and another for dropdown.If I scroll the tableview after filling the data in textfields it was removing(data in textfields is removing).Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: You must save your text to an data array, and fill it to cell in `cellForRow` datasource.

Comment: You are missing the concept of reuse in `UITableView` (and `UICollectionView`). Update your model.

Comment: I didn't get you exactly,Can you please explain it clearly.

Comment: The suggested duplicate link explains the issue and gives a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening bcoz table view cell is reusing(if you dequeued cell, hope you did).

To overcome this, you need to set cell data i.e. textfield data in `cellForRowAt:`, if user has already entered value init.

You need to track what value is added in which cell textfields so when cell is  about to visible `cellForRowAt:` will be called and you set data in it, so data won't be erased.